# Proving the Sine Law using dot product.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, inner-products

Suppose we have a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with distinct vertices $A,B,C$ joined by sides with length $a=\rm{dist}(B,C)$, $b=\rm{dist}(A,C)$, $c=\rm{dist}(A,B)$ and have angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ at A,B,C respectively. Using only properties of the dot product is it possible to prove the sine law, that is $$\frac{\sin \alpha}{a}=\frac{\sin \beta}{b}=\frac{\sin \gamma}{c}$$ I have begun by rewriting $\frac{\sin \alpha}{a}$ in terms of distances and dot products, leaving me with

$$\frac{1}{\rm{dist}(B,C)}\sqrt{\left(1-\left(\frac{(C-A)\cdot(A-B)}{\rm{dist}(A,B)\rm{dist}(A,C)}\right)^2\right)}$$
Using the fact that $\cos \alpha= \frac{(C-A)\cdot(A-B)}{\rm{dist}(A,B)\rm{dist}(A,C)}$ and $\sin (\cos^{-1} (x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Is this a correct way to start because now it seems to me like I'm stuck?

Comment: Hint: $\operatorname{dist}(A,B)^2=(A-B)\cdot(A-B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $d$ for $\operatorname{dist},$ and use that $$d(X,Y)^2=(X-Y)\cdot(X-Y).$$ Letting $\alpha=B-C,\beta =C-A,\gamma =A-B,$ Then your formula is:

$$\frac{\sqrt{(\gamma\cdot \gamma)(\beta \cdot \beta)-(\beta \cdot \gamma)^2}} {d(B,C)d(A,C)d(A,B)}
$$

Expand what is inside the square root. Use $\alpha+\gamma+\beta=0.$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to expand the square root? I've just gone in a loop and done $(\gamma \cdot \gamma)=c^2, (\beta \cdot \beta) = b^2, (\beta \cdot \gamma) = bc \cos \alpha$ and that simply makes it reduce back to what I started with?

Comment: Try replacing $\beta=-(\alpha +\gamma).$ @Jacob